# WPF Datagrid привязка к XML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

#### Имеется:

Форма с `datagrid`, текстбоксами и кнопкой "Добавить"

#### Задача:

После заполнения текстбоксов и нажатия на кнопку "Добавить" в `xml` файл добавляется новая запись и сразу же отображается в `datagrid`
При редактировании ячейки в `datagrid` изменения проецируются на xml файл

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего реализовать привязку xml к датагриду в этом случае? Приложение построено с применением паттерна MVVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, можно например так:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elements[Item]}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Grid.Row="0">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Название"
                Binding="{Binding Attribute[Name].Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Смещение"
                Binding="{Binding Attribute[Offset].Value}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                Binding="{Binding Attribute[ID].Value}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="AddMore">More!</Button>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public XDocument Document { get; private set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Document = new XDocument(new XElement("Root"));
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = Document.Root;
    }

    int index = 0;
    void AddMore(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        index++;
        var newItem = new XElement("Item",
                            new XAttribute("Name", "Element " + index),
                            new XAttribute("Offset", "Offset " + index),
                            new XAttribute("ID", "Id " + index));
        Document.Root.Add(newItem);
    }
}
```

Чтение значений атрибутов из текстбоксов и сохранение `XDocument`'а в файл, надеюсь, сможете самостоятельно. (Ну и логику, понятно, нужно вынести во вью-модель, как обычно.)

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам! Уже не первый раз выручаете.

Comment: @Zer0CooL: Пожалуйста!